# How to stop TS from flagging an already check value so I don't need to use @ts-ignore?

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, backend, koa

I'm building an api using Koa js using Typescript.
My front-end sends requests and adds the user's firebase access token inside the headers.
Then I verify the token with firebase-admin inside node.

An example:

```
const token = ctx.headers.token
    const passid = ctx.params.passid

    try {
        if (!token) {
            ctx.throw(401)
        }
        const uid = await verifyToken(token)
```

Problem is that typescript throws this error

```
Argument of type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Only solution I've found is adding `// @ts-ignore` above the call to the verifyToken function.

Is there a better way to do this?